# MEMORY LAYOUT IN C

Tags: c, memory, layout, memory-layout

I am learning about this topic called **Memory Layout in C**

But memory are of different types like *primary memory (ram), secondary memory (like hard disk) or registers* I think [THE DIAGRAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZ9qu.jpg)

So in this diagram (attached here with) which memory is it referring to? Like is it ram, hard-disk or something else ??

Comment: Please note that this has nothing to do with the C language as such - it is a general computer question. Most mainstream desktop OS like Linux or Windows simply like to use C for the code closest to the hardware.

Answer (score 2):

On most modern operating systems, it refers to the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of a process.

Only part of this address space is actually mapped to physical RAM. Most of this address space is probably not mapped at all, and some of it may be stored on secondary storage such as a hard disk, due to [memory paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_paging).

Comment: Thanks, it cleared a lot of my doubts :)

Answer (score 0):

Addressable memory always refers to RAM (or flash in case of embedded systems). The picture looks like the memory layout of an executable process in a PC, all of it uploaded in RAM.

You won't be able to directly access HD memory through an address, because it is accessed through an external bus interface and that part is handled by an OS.

My answer here might be helpful: [What gets allocated on the stack and the heap?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277536)

Comment: So it this type of layout followed in all programming language, or is it C which uses the memory (RAM here) in this way?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and also for the link embedded - helped me a lot to understand more about memories :)

Comment: @xXxINSANExXx It's the process memory layout, so it's fairly close to the OS and hardware. Higher layer languages abstract things further and typically don't get into details about where data is stored.